# mainWindow.webContents.send does not work

Tags: node.js, axios, electron

I am trying to send response from python axios.post to ipcRenderer but mainWindow.webContents does not send the response to renderer and sometime the response from axios is delayed
please help me with this

main.js

```
axios.post(`${pythonHost}/send-request/`,options)
.then(function(response){
mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function () {
mainWindow.webContents.send('request_status:success',JSON.stringify(response.data))
});
});
```

index.js

```
ipcRenderer.on('request_status:success',(e,response)=>{
\\
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `mainWindow.webContents.send` will never run unless [`did-finish-load`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-did-finish-load) is fired. This event will only fire when the page has loaded and it won't fire again

So in your case, you are just waiting forever for an event that won't get fired and you are never executing `mainWindow.webContents.send`

```js
axios.post(`${pythonHost}/send-request/`, options).then(function (response) {
  mainWindow.webContents.on("did-finish-load", function () {
    // this will not run until the "did-finish-load" fires !
    mainWindow.webContents.send(
      "request_status:success",
      JSON.stringify(response.data)
    );
  });
});
```

You probably want to do something like this instead

```js
const { once } = require("events");

let didFinishLoad = false;

mainWindow.webContents.on("did-finish-load", function () {
  didFinishLoad = true;
});

axios
  .post(`${pythonHost}/send-request/`, options)
  .then(async function (response) {
    if (!didFinishLoad) {
      // wait until did-finish-load is fired
      await once(mainWindow.webContents, "did-finish-load");
    }

    mainWindow.webContents.send(
      "request_status:success",
      JSON.stringify(response.data)
    );
  });
```